# PHP + MySQLi - Trying to use enctype="multipart/form-data" to upload an image to the users row in the localhost DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, multipartform-data

I am creating a user profile update page for the user logged in to edit their name, email, and profile picture. I have the text updating successfully, but I cannot get the picture update to work. There is no error produced, but the field in the DB changes from null to " " (blank). I have pasted my update account page code below, any help figuring out what is going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php require 'Assets/Connections/Connections.php'; ?>
<?php session_start(); 
    if(isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){
    }else{
        header('Location: LogIn.php');
        die();
        }
?>
<?php

    $User = $_SESSION["UserID"];

    $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE UserID ='$User'");

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    $_SESSION["FirstName"] = $row['Fname'];
    $_SESSION["LastName"] = $row['Lname'];
    $_SESSION["Email"] = $row['Email'];
    $_SESSION["PW"] = $row['Password'];
    #$_SESSION["Picture"] = $row['ProfilePicture'];
?>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['Update'])){

            $UpdateFName = $_POST['FirstName'];
            $UpdateLName = $_POST['LastName'];
            $UpdateEmail = $_POST['Email'];
            $UpdatePassword = $_POST['Password'];
            $StorePassword = password_hash($UpdatePassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'Assests/Images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
                    #move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"Assets/Images/".$_FILES['file']['name']);


            $sql = $con->query("UPDATE user SET Fname = '{$UpdateFName}', Lname = '{$UpdateLName}', Email = '{$UpdateEmail}', Password = '{$StorePassword}', ProfileImage = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE UserID = $User");

            header('Location: Account.php');
            die();
                                }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="Assets/CSS/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Assets/CSS/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Update Account</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="Header"></div>
        <div class="Menu">
            <div id="Menu">
                 <nav>
                    <ul class="cssmenu">

                        <li><a href="Home.php">Home</a></li>

                        <li><a href="Account.php">Account</a></li>

                        <li><a href="Projects.php">Projects</a></li>    

                        <li><a href="Users.php">Users</a></li>  

                        <li><a href="LogOut.php">LogOut</a></li>

                    </ul>
                 </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="LeftBody"></div>
        <div class="RightBody">
          <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
            <div class="FormElement">
                <input name="FirstName" type="text" class="TField" id="FirstName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["FirstName"]; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="FormElement">
                <input name="LastName" type="text" class="TField" id="LastName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["LastName"]; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="FormElement">
                <input name="Email" type="email" class="TField" id="Email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Email"]; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="FormElement">
                <input name="Password" type="password" class="TField" id="Password" placeholder="Password" required="requried">
            </div>
            <div class="FormElement" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file">
                <br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="FormElement">
                <input name="Update" type="submit" class="button" id="Update" value="Submit Changes">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="Footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `form` element need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to upload files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form element need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to upload files

You form tag would be

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Wraf off `action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"` from your `div`

```
 <div class="FormElement" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file">
                <br><br>
            </div>
```

These are form element. You mention these thingn in your form

```
<div class="FormElement">
                <input type="file" name="file">
                <br><br>
            </div>
```

Read [form](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. My div inside my form has the enctype. Does it have to be in the form element?

Comment: You need to remove that part from your div!! those are form element add this things into your form

Comment: Thank you that now updates the DB, however it does not add the image to the folder I specified at:                                                  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'Assests/Images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);

Comment: My bad I had a typo in the folder name! Embarrassing lol, thanks for your help! Star :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem with tour form tag, update by this

```js
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```